# Dll built in .net 3.5 using VS2008 throws exception when deployed on a .net 4 installed XP system

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-3.5

My dll is built on VS2008 with target framework as 3.5. The main application is in C++ and use C++/CLI to talk with the .net dll. 
When the application is deployed on an XP system where .net 4  alone is installed, an exception occurred where two of the assemblies are missing.

System.Core Version 3.5.0.0 and System.Web.Extensions 3.5.0.0

After reading, a solution is referred as adding

```
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
```

to the configuration to force the use of framework 4. I don't have a config file to set supportedRuntime to 4 since i built it as a class library.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create an app.exe.config file where "app" is the name of your C++ .exe file.  Don't forget useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy = true.

Comment: Thank you Hans, but this throws the famous error  - "this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. reinstalling this application may fix problem."

Comment: Seems like 
`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>`
made some difference. 
The order is also important, i guess. For the app to work with a 3.5 framework if framework 4 is not present the order seems to be
`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
 
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set that flag at run-time (I suppose you have some kind of activation code), check this post: http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/.

It worked perfectly many times.

Answer (score 1):

Add the configuration to `.exe.config` for each single executable using the library.

In case of COM services that would be `dllhost.exe.config` although that is ugly security-wise and worth additional thought about alternatives if you confirm that this is your case.